Language as bijective function
In mathematics, bijective function is the function for which every one value of the argument corresponds to one and only one value of the function. Is there any language which would come close to having this concept for words and meanings? Meaning that each word means only one thing or concept and each thing or concept has only one word to describe it. That could probably be some artificial language but I have no idea where and how should I start the search.

Does this answer your question (I think any language meeting your requirement would necessarily also meet the requirement there)? Is it possible to construct a language that is not semantically ambiguous?

@Tristan yes, it does, thank you.
